# How Do I Override the Standard Controller's Save Action in My Controller Extension?

Tags: controller, controller-extension

I am trying to build a controller extension for the Opportunity standard controller.

According to [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_def.htm) and [stackexchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32720/how-to-override-save-method-in-standard-controller-extension) I ought to be able to override the Save() action in the controller extension. I have a VF page that is embedded in the standard Opportunity layout and a save() method in the controller extension, but the save() method in my controller extension never gets called.

What am I doing wrong?

The VF page - embedded in the standard Opportunity layout:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="TestExtension" showHeader="false" >
</apex:page>
```

The controller extension class - I get the constructor debug message, but not the one from save():

```
public without sharing class TestExtension {

    ApexPages.StandardController stdController = null;

    public TestExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.stdController = stdController;
        System.debug('==== TestExtension: TestExtension() ====');
    }
    public PageReference save() {       
        System.debug('==== TestExtension: save() ====');
        // do some stuff
        Pagereference ref = stdController.save();
        // some more stuff
        // give control back to standard controller
        return ref;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't inject a single method override, but instead have to override one of the standard actions with a complete replacement page. Then your method will be called. Can't find a good e.g. Trailhead on this, but hopefully someone else will.

Comment: Keith: yes I could probably put a Save button in my extension page and trap the user into pressing it instead of the parent window Save button. But I definitely do not want to replace the entire standard page with a VF page, not least because I would lose the comfort of (_no code!!!_) modification of the Layout. The terms extension and override used in the documentation in this context seem to be not more than a pretty ludicrous make-believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples you are referencing only apply if your controller extension is managing the entire page. You cannot change the standard save behavior for an object by embedding a Visualforce page in its layout; page embedding is not a "hook" into the save process.

Your only *direct* solution is [overriding](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_lex_s1_action_overrides.htm) [the entire action](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/workshop-override-standard-action/override_4) with a Visualforce page or Lightning (Aura) component, which requires you to reimplement the page layout. It's an expensive, clumsy, inflexible solution that I usually recommend against.

In most cases, a better solution is to *rethink your overall objective* such that you can achieve it with some combination of

- Quick Actions, for streamlining create operations with prepopulated fields.
- Screen Flows, for interactive wizard-style UIs.
- Apex triggers or record-save flows, for non-UI automation.

Comment: Very well explained.

Comment: I am going to rethink my problem in the light of your suggestions. If I then still don't see how to solve my problem, I will come back.

Comment: ευρηκα ηδη: this question and my earlier one [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/362526/publish-a-platform-event-from-within-a-platform-event-apex-trigger-question) were posted in the context made clear in the latter. And the solution is: as simple as a record-triggered (after update) Flow.